# Como simular um ob_flush() no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Eu tenho um formulário no qual faço um upload. E as vezes o arquivo de upload é grande. Meu site está na AWS usando o Load Balancer.

O Load Balancer espera uma resposta da requisição em um determinado tempo. Porém, a requisição é POST.

Como faço para *printar* na **blade** o que está sendo feito?

No PHP tradicional eu usaria o `ob_flush()`, `flush()`.

Mas no Laravel não consegui reproduzir isso.

Comment: No caso seria com PHP FPM ou o PHP normal?

Comment: O PHP é normal, sem FPM.

Comment: Eu fiz uma implementação dessas, cara. Se quiser dar uma olhada tá no meu [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/3310e63610797776a1bbd86ab91054ac)